# How to get objects value if its name contains dots?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a very simple array (please focus on the object with `"points.bean.pointsBase"` as key):

```
var mydata =   
{"list":  
  [  
    {"points.bean.pointsBase":  
      [  
        {"time": 2000, "caption":"caption text", duration: 5000},  
        {"time": 6000, "caption":"caption text", duration: 3000}  
      ]  
    }  
  ]  
};  
 
// Usually we make smth like this to get the value: 
var smth = mydata.list[0].points.bean.pointsBase[0].time; 
alert(smth); // should display 2000
```

But, unfortunately, it displays nothing. When I change `"points.bean.pointsBase"` to something without dots in its name - everything works.

However, I can't change this name to anything else without dots, but I need to get a value? Is there any options to get it?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

What you want is:

```
var smth = mydata.list[0]["points.bean.pointsBase"][0].time;
```

In JavaScript, any field you can access using the . operator, you can access using [] with a string version of the field name.

Answer (score 34):

in javascript, object properties can be accessed with . operator or with associative array indexing using []. ie. `object.property` is equivalent to `object["property"]`

this should do the trick

```
var smth = mydata.list[0]["points.bean.pointsBase"][0].time;
```

Answer (score 26):

Try `["points.bean.pointsBase"]`

Answer (score 21):

If json object key/name contains dot......! like

```
var myJson = {"my.name":"vikas","my.age":27}
```

Than you can access like

```
myJson["my.name"]
myJson["my.age"]
```