# Load Data using ajax. Dots issue

Tags: javascript

This is my JSON file:

```
{
    "d.3.o35.data": {
      "name": "level",
      "value": 113,
    },
    "d.3.o36.data": {
      "name": "level",
      "value": 255,
    },
    "d.3.o37.data": {
      "name": "level",
      "value": 255,
    },
  "updateTime": 1397565031
}
```

And this is my ajax script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'config/json',
    dataType: "JSON",
    async : false,
    success: function(answer) {

        var odp = answer.d.3.o37.data.value
        alert(odp);

    },
    error: function(answer) {
        alert("Error")
    }
});
```

I want to alert value of any of this but it is not working when dots are JSON objects. How to call objects with dots ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets:

```
var odp = answer['d.3.o37.data'].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

either:

```
var odp = answer['d.3.o37.data'].value;
```

or:

```
var odp = answer['d.3.o37.data']['value'];
```

Also, you should avoid ending JSON objects with a comma, for instance:

```
{ "name": "level", "value": 113 }
```

is better than:

```
{ "name": "level", "value": 113, }
```

because some JSON parsers will reject the latter and none will reject the former.