# Jquery Get specific values from JSON result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I select some fields from this Json Result or response
which has the blow format

```
var WPQ3ListData = { "Row" : 
[{
  "ID": "27",
  "PermMask": "0x400001f07fff1bff",
  "FSObjType": "0",
  "Title": "NOOO",
  "FileLeafRef": "27_.000",
  "TotalCost": "87",
  "TotalCost.": "87.0000000000000",
  "TC1ID": "23",
  "TotalCost.SUM": "160"
}]
}
```

for example I want to select TotalCost.SUM value and store it into a variable
on document.ready of jQuery

Comment: That response is coming from SharePoint 2013 why it is wrong

Comment: You think that Microsoft made mistake

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch it using `WPQ3ListData.row[0]["TotalCost.SUM"]`

```
var WPQ3ListData = { "Row" : 
[{
  "ID": "27",
  "PermMask": "0x400001f07fff1bff",
  "FSObjType": "0",
  "Title": "NOOO",
  "FileLeafRef": "27_.000",
  "TotalCost": "87",
  "TotalCost.": "87.0000000000000",
  "TC1ID": "23",
  "TotalCost.SUM": "160"
}]
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  var valueReq = WPQ3ListData.Row[0]["TotalCost.SUM"];
});
```

Comment: I think `row` should be `Row`

Comment: @hawk Yep a typo.. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: Thinks it worked perfect you put Row in small case upper case worked var valueReq = WPQ3ListData.Row[0]["TotalCost.SUM"];

Answer (score 0):

It should be done with associative array indexing ie, object["property"]

```
var WPQ3ListData = { "Row" : 
[{
  "ID": "27",
  "PermMask": "0x400001f07fff1bff",
  "FSObjType": "0",
  "Title": "NOOO",
  "FileLeafRef": "27_.000",
  "TotalCost": "87",
  "TotalCost.": "87.0000000000000",
  "TC1ID": "23",
  "TotalCost.SUM": "160"
}]
}



$(document).ready(function(){
  var value = WPQ3ListData.Row[0]["TotalCost.SUM"];
});
```

Comment: In `JSON.parse()` first argument must be `text` corresponding to JSON as string.

Comment: Mistake on my end. It should be done with associative array indexing. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
`WPQ3ListData.Row[0]["TotalCost.SUM"]`

    var WPQ3ListData = { "Row" : 
    [{
      "ID": "27",
      "PermMask": "0x400001f07fff1bff",
      "FSObjType": "0",
      "Title": "NOOO",
      "FileLeafRef": "27_.000",
      "TotalCost": "87",
      "TotalCost.": "87.0000000000000",
      "TC1ID": "23",
      "TotalCost.SUM": "160"
    }]
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var requestValue = WPQ3ListData.Row[0]["TotalCost.SUM"];
    });
```