# how to use a json object in which its name is foo.txt. I want to print element of this object?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I just doing with javascricpt and json. I want to get data from api in which object have some details, here i want to print details of a object named "foo.txt" have some element like size, raw_url, content etc. And I want raw_url.

How can I accomplish the following:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.files.foo(?)['raw_url']
Json is here :-
object {url: "https://api.github.com/gists/884c8343dca5b322bf6f", forks_url: "https://api.github.com/gists/884c8343dca5b322bf6f/forks", commits_url: "https://api.github.com/gists/884c8343dca5b322bf6f/commits", id: "884c8343dca5b322bf6f", git_pull_url: "https://gist.github.com/884c8343dca5b322bf6f.git"…}
comments: 0
comments_url: "https://api.github.com/gists/884c8343dca5b322bf6f/comments"
commits_url: "https://api.github.com/gists/884c8343dca5b322bf6f/commits"
created_at: "2015-11-19T09:35:23Z"
description: "test"
files: Object
foo.txt: Object
content: "sdfasfd"
filename: "foo.txt"
language: "Text"
raw_url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/884c8343dca5b322bf6f/raw/5234994707b7b85bec9c80e50cb0b7dfca050e3b/foo.txt"
size: 7
truncated: false
type: "text/plain"
```

Comment: I hope this will help you . [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)    Add your mock json , to clear idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to access the property? You don't have to access properties with the dot syntax (`myObject.foo.txt`), which obviously causes problems here. Just access it with square brackets:

```
myObject['foo.txt']
```

```js
var myObject = { 'foo.txt': 'Hello World!' };
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = myObject['foo.txt'];
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has `Object.toSource()` which prints object as JSON or you can install Firebug and print with `console.log(object)`

Comment: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.files.foo['type']