# How to extract Json object value if object name contains period?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

Here is my JSON code and as u can see first object name *"com.app.connect.model.Login"* contain periods.

```
{
  "com.app.connect.model.Login": {
    "status": "FAIL",
    "message": "Incorrect username or password."
  }
}
```

I want to extract "status" value. I can get "status" value if object name doesn't contain period.

```
var statusJson2 = jsonCC2.comappconnectmodelLoginStatus.status;
```

I tried many things but I couldn't achieve.

```
var jsonCC = { "com.app.connect.model.LoginStatus": { "status": "FAIL", "message": "Incorrect username or password." } };

var jsonCC2 = { "comappconnectmodelLoginStatus": { "status": "FAIL", "message": "Incorrect username or password." } };

//var statusJson = jsonCC.["com.app.connect.model.LoginStatus"].status;

var statusJson2 = jsonCC2.comappconnectmodelLoginStatus.status;

//console.log(statusJson)

console.log(statusJson2)
```

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)

Comment: @Pat I saw this question and answer. I tried it too but the example is array and I couldn't apply for this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do:

```
var subObject = jsonCC["com.app.connect.model.Login"];
```

Don't put a period between `jsonCC` and `[`

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9txrqwdo/) of the working code.

Comment: I tried but I'm getting error : Cannot read property 'com.app.connect.model.LoginStatus' of undefined

Comment: @ObsessiO Your JSON is just `com.app.connect.mod‌​el.Login`

Comment: yes I made typo mistake when I carry code to stackoverflow.
When I removed period between `jsonCC` and `[` works fine. Thank you.