# Reading values from a flatten JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have created an array (named boxesList) of flatten Json objects, where each of these objects looks like this:

```
Object{
   iips:"ALP872"
   box.number:142
   box.color:"blue"
   box.size:11
}
```

When I try to extract in my application the data stored in these objects:

```
for(let boxElement of boxesList){
    console.log(boxElement.iips);
    console.log(boxElement.box.number);
}
```

I do not have issue getting the iips value, but I do get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined' when trying to get box.number. Does anyone know how can this be achieved?

Comment: boxElement['box.number']

Comment: You cannot have a `.` in a name of your object, or you have to get it like `boxElement['box.number']`. But that you should also see already in the serialized way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)

Comment: did u Try boxesList.box.number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You property key is `box.number`

`boxElement.box.number` calls the `number` property inside the `box` property

```js
var boxesList = [{
   "iips":"ALP872",
   "box.number":142,
   "box.color":"blue",
   "box.size":11
}]

for(let boxElement of boxesList){
    console.log(boxElement.iips);
    console.log(boxElement["box.number"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to use the `boxElement['box.number']` syntax.

The boxElement is indexed on strings like `box.number`, rather than on two layers.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have an object property name with a dot in it. What you're looking to do above can be achieved if 'box' is a property of the main object with 'number', 'color' and 'size' being it's properties.

Something like this:

```
var mainObj = {
   iips:"ALP872",
   box: {
       number:142,
       color:"blue",
       size:11
   }
}
```