# How to read a parameter with a period using Express in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My macro is called from a url containing parameters like:

```
?title=TitleHere&macro.id=a1
```

I'm finding it easy to pick up the title, but I am getting an error when trying to get the macro.id parameter as follows.

```
var requestTitle = req.query.title;
var requestMacroId = req.query.macro.id;
```

What is the correct way to get a parameter with a period in the name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)

Comment: @str it's about express node.js module, not about parsing json.

Comment: @Thomas try `req.query['macro.id']`.

Comment: @alexmac It is not specific to the module, but to how you access properties. The same concepts apply.

Comment: The context is different enough that I wouldn't have known that question had the same answer. Thanks to @alexmac and kGielo, it's solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var requestTitle = req.query['title'];
var requestMacroId = req.query['macro.id'];
```