# AngularJS: Read array with variables with dot

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I have the following result from database (using sequelize), the result:

JSON from the database:

```
 [{"codSparePart":"SP001","name":"NAME","description":"DESCRIPTION","codProject":1,"available":1,"codManufacturer":1,"stock":4,"manufacturer.name":"MAN1","manufacturer.description":"DES1","manufacturer.codManufacturer":1}]
```

In the controller I do the next:

```
 vm.spareParts = data.data;
            console.log('-------- ' + JSON.stringify(vm.spareParts));
            for (var i = 0; i < vm.spareParts.length; i++) {
                vm.items.push({
                    codSparePart: vm.spareParts[i].codSparePart,
                    name: vm.spareParts[i].name,
                    description: vm.spareParts[i].description,
                    available: vm.spareParts[i].available,
                    codManufacturer: vm.spareParts[i].codManufacturer,
                    nameManufacturer: vm.sparePart[i]['manufacturer.description'],
                    stock: vm.spareParts[i].stock,
                    codProject: vm.spareParts[i].codProject
                });
```

All is working perfectly except in reading the variables with dot.
      `nameManufacturer: vm.sparePart[i]['manufacturer.description']
nameManufacturer: vm.sparePart[i]['manufacturer.name']`

How can I read these variables, I'm looking for the solution but I think is too simple and there is not any information about it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, change `vm.sparePart` to `vm.spareParts`

> This line: `nameManufacturer: vm.sparePart[i]['manufacturer.description'],`

Comment: Thank you, stupid question for stupid error. I`m sorry for the question. I'm a beginner and some times the things are not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working perfectly:

```js
const array =[{"codSparePart":"SP001","name":"NAME","description":"DESCRIPTION","codProject":1,"available":1,"codManufacturer":1,"stock":4,"manufacturer.name":"MAN1","manufacturer.description":"DES1","manufacturer.codManufacturer":1}]

console.log(array[0]['manufacturer.description']);
```

More information: [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)