# Parse value from JSON when key contains dot (period) in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, jsonpath

[image]

In the above example, I would like to get the value "Bug" from "System.WorkItemType"

using

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Url $someUri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers
$wit = response.fields.System.WorkItemType
```

doesn't work since the dot / period messes it up.

In javascript there is this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots) but did not work in Powershell.

Using regex to replace the dot with underscore seems too farfetched (and I didn't get it to work, but used -match -convertFrom-Json -replace -convertTo-Json so maybe did it wrong?

So my question is simply: How do I get the 'Bug' value from the 'System.WorkItemType' key? (bug may be other strings...)

Comment: You can use quotes so that it's parsed literally, try `$wit = response.fields.'System.WorkItemType'` or `$wit = response.fields."System.WorkItemType"` (both should work).

Comment: Thtat did the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you put the property names in `""` or `''`, you should be able to get what you are looking for:

```
$json= @'
 { "id" : 9983,
    "rev" : 17,
    "fields" :{
    "System.AreaPath":"Cloud\\Dev Blue Team",
    "System.TeamProject":"Cloud"
    }
}
'@

$j = $Json | convertfrom-json
$j.fields."System.AreaPath"
$J.fields.'System.TeamProject'
```

if you need to escape double quotes, use the `` ` `` [grave accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/60/index.htm), known as the *backtick* in PowerShell.

```
"area path = $($j.fields.`"System.AreaPath`")"
```