# Can't get data from JSON status undefined?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get the `status` of `de.zip-code` but get a error `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`. In my js file I have this

`$.getJSON("link", function(json) { let creditcheck = json.de_zip_code.status;` and more.

```
{
de.zip-code: {
   status: "RED",
   link: "link",
   text: "text"
},
glasvezel-availability: {
   status: "RED",
   link: "link",
   text: "text"
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like JSON, this looks like a JS object...

Comment: Do you see the difference between `.`, `-` and `_`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use the same name as your property when trying to access it (`creditcheck = json.de_zip_code.status` won't work).

If that property contains special characters (`.` and `-` here), then you must use the bracket notation instead of dot notation to access the property:

```
data['de.zip-code'].status
```

See the [doc about property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```js
const data = {
  'de.zip-code': {
     status: 'RED',
     link: 'link',
     text: 'text'
  },
  'glasvezel-availability': {
     status: 'RED',
     link: 'link',
     text: 'text'
  }
};

console.log(data['de.zip-code'].status);
```

Comment: Thanks I changed this 'data['de.zip-code'].status' to let creditcheck = json['de.zip-code'].status; and it works thanks for your help!!

Comment: You are welcome!