# Cannot access keys inside Object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to access the value of a key inside a Javascript object. My object currently looks like:

```
const options = {
  "account.country": getCountry,
  "account.phone": getPhone,
}
```

When I `console.log(options)`, it shows the whole object. But, when I try

```
console.log(options.account) // undefined, 
console.log(options.account.country) // error.
```

I don't understand why. I also tried:

```
 const parsedObj = JSON.parse(options);
 console.log(parsedObj);
```

But it just returns

> 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1'

Comment: what is `getCountry` and `getPhone` ?

Comment: `options["account.country"]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots) and [How to access object properties containing special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704)

Comment: You should not JSON.parse an object.

Comment: The key is "account.country".. you'll have to use bracket notation. `options['account.country']`. As for `JSON.parse`... that's for parsing JSON strings. If you want to turn a JS object into JSON use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: JSON.parse(options) is not needed. options is allready object. If you wish to parse options must be string, options = '...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Bracket Notation when you want to access the property from a string.

```js
const options = {
  "account.country": 'getCountry',
  "account.phone": 'getPhone',
}
console.log(options['account.country'])
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I console.log 'options', it shows the whole object

Because it is an object

> when I console.log options.account it returns undefined

Because there is no `account` property.

Only `account.country` and `account.phone`. So you have to access properties with those explicit names, like this:

```
console.log(options['account.country']);
```

> But it just returns 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1'

It's an object, not a string of JSON.

Comment: This answer doesn't do anything to help the user understand the concepts he clearly doesn't.

Comment: @Jhawins — It clearly explains why the existing attempts fail, and demonstrates the modification needed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const options = {
  "account.country": 'getCountry',
  "account.phone": 'getPhone',
}
```

You can access the desired value using `options['account.country']`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let options = {
  "account.country": "getCountry",
  "account.phone": "getPhone"
}
console.log(options["account.country"])
```

Comment: It would've been more helpful to show how to build a proper object (as that was the OP intent)

Answer (score 0):

The `.` in object key name is causing this issue. When you do:

> options.account it returns undefined

^ that is because there is no key with name `account`

> when I console log 'options.account.country' it errors

^ that is because it tries to look for key `country` on undefined (options.account)

You can solve this by using array indexing syntax as follow:

```
options['account.country']

options['account.phone']
```