# Mapping a dot notation key in an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
let object = {
  seniority: 'director_level',
  'address.long_form': 'Phoenix, AZ, United States'
}
```

when I go to print `address.long_form` like this I get an error.

```
console.log(object.address.long_form)
```

How do get the value for 'address.long_form'?

Comment: Try `console.log(object['address.long_form'])`. And better yet, don't name your object fields with dots.

Comment: I was wrong about this one. Here's a link, [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `address.long_form` is in string, you cannot use dot notation instead use this

```
console.log(object['address.long_form'])
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work like this: `object["address.long_form"]`, but just don't use dots in object indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can still extract it but you can't use the literal notation, you need to use the `[]` notation in order to get past the ambiguity.

i.e.

```
console.log(object['address.long_form'])
```

Of course better would to just avoid keys in that form, but depends on your data.