# Typescript - How to parse JSON to object if its key contains dots?

Tags: json, typescript

Like [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots), how do I use JSON.parse() function to make it an object?

For a JSON:

```
const mydata = {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2.part2": "value2" 
};
```

How should I define the class?

```
class MyData {
   key1: string;
   key2.part2: string;
}
```

`key2.part2` would be invalid in a class.

Comment: There's no JSON in your question so you already have your answer -> `"key2.part2"`

Comment: You should use `interface`, not `class`. A `class` in JavaScript and TypeScript defines a constructor (and optionally: function properties), whereas JSON objects only have data properties, not function properties).

Comment: _"how do I use JSON.parse() function to make it an object?"_ - Keys in an object are always strings, hence `JSON.parse()` will just return that: `"key2.part2"`