# RedisJSON and Python3: JSON.get and ft('index').search(Query('@orig_ip:{192\.168\.210\.27}')) returning no results (matching entry in redis)

Tags: python-3.x, redis, redis-py, redisearch, redisjson

I am new to redis and created an index and am attempting to ingest [Zeek Logging Data](https://docs.zeek.org/en/master/), create an index for multiple fields, and then search fields in that index. For the life of me, I cannot get any values to return when searching for the `@orig_ip` name or using JSON.GET to retried any `id.*` related fields.

**UPDATE: I figured this out after more troubleshooting and am updating here to help anyone else struggling with this problem.**

### Here is my WRONG code for creating the index:

```py
# Options for index creation
index_def = IndexDefinition(
                index_type=IndexType.JSON,
                prefix = ['uid:'],
                score = 0.5,
                score_field = 'doc_score'
)

# Schema definition
schema = (  
            TagField('$.orig_l2_addr', as_name='orig_mac'),
            TagField('$.id.orig_h', as_name='orig_ip'), #Wrong field path
            TagField('$.id.resp_h', as_name='resp_ip'), #Wrong field path
            NumericField('$.orig_bytes', as_name='orig_bytes'),
            NumericField('$.resp_bytes', as_name='resp_bytes'),
            NumericField('$.ts', as_name='timestamp')
)

r.ft('py_conn_idx').create_index(schema, definition = index_def)
```

### Here is the result I kept getting with the above WRONG `schema` (no results)

```
search_result4 = r.ft('py_conn_idx').search(Query('@orig_ip:{192\.168\.210\.27}'))
```

```
Results for "@orig_ip:{192\.168\.210\.27}":
0
```

### UPDATE: Working `schema` definition:

So it turns out even though `Zeek` is only using the `.` in field names vice using it to create an object, but the `.` in the field names was the culprit in my query failures. I needed to access the fields for the index as follows:

```
# Schema definition
schema = (  
            TagField('$.orig_l2_addr', as_name='orig_mac'),
            TagField('$.["id.orig_h"]', as_name='orig_ip'), #Fixed field reference
            TagField('$.["id.resp_h"]', as_name='resp_ip'), #Fixed field reference
            NumericField('$.orig_bytes', as_name='orig_bytes'),
            NumericField('$.resp_bytes', as_name='resp_bytes'),
            NumericField('$.ts', as_name='timestamp')
)
```

After recreating the index with this `schema`, I get results with my query:

```
Results for "@orig_ip:{192\.168\.210\.27}":
Document {'id': 'uid:CPvYfTI4Zb1Afp2l5',....
```

Thanks to this stackoverflow question for finally walking me to the cause of my troubles: [How to get objects value if its name contains dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this answer here so this question gets marked as having one. See the updated question/code above!