# Limit max and min time in input HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I have a simple code that allows the user to enter minutes and seconds (website is written in react).

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <input defaultValue="0" maxlength="2"/>
  </span>
<span>m</span>
<span>
    <input defaultValue="10" maxLength='2' />
  </span>
  <span>s</span>
</div>
```

But I would like to improve my functionality and that’s why I’m turning to you.

Currently the user can enter any number <= 99 (and in the seconds column he can enter 99) and any characters, but I would like the user to be able to enter a time of at least 5 seconds and at most 20 minutes.

Tell me how to limit the entered characters to numbers only and limit the maximum and minimum entered time.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes, your option works, thanks! But still the user can still enter a time period of 20 minutes 30 seconds and I would like to limit the maximum time to 20 minutes 0 seconds

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77474249/edit) the question to include a [mre], including state variables, the complete function responsible for rendering the existing JSX, etc. See [ask] for more info.

Comment: @nazarmammedov, please refrain from removing `reactjs` tag from questions about form elements. React has its own particularities in dealing with forms and, even when the JSX looks like plain HTML, the `reactjs` tag means the user is looking for a react-friendly solution. In general, you should refrain from removing tags of technologies outside your domain of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an `<input type="number" />` with the appropriate `min` and `max`.

To achieve the custom limitation, here's a proof of concept, keeping the time value (in seconds) inside a state and then transforming it into amounts of minutes and seconds for each input:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React
const limitValue = (min, max, val) => Math.min(max, Math.max(min, val))
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10)
  const onInput = useCallback(
    (val, minutes) =>
      setValue((prev) =>
        limitValue(
          5,
          1200,
          minutes ? val * 60 + (prev % 60) : ~~(prev / 60) * 60 + val
        )
      ),
    []
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <span>
        <input
          type="number"
          min={0}
          max={20}
          value={~~(value / 60)}
          onInput={({ target: { value } }) => onInput(+value, true)}
        />
        m
      </span>
      <span>
        <input
          type="number"
          min={-1}
          max={60}
          value={value % 60}
          onInput={({ target: { value } }) => onInput(+value)}
        />
        s
      </span>
      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(
          {
            value,
            minutes: ~~(value / 60),
            seconds: value % 60
          },
          null,
          2
        )}
      </pre>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. I didn't vote against it. I would like to ask you about improvements: at the moment the user can manually enter any number, can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: I see what you mean, yeah, you need to use `Math.min()` and `Math.max()`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes thank you! But we can still enter a time period, for example, as 20 minutes 30 seconds, and the maximum should be 20 minutes

Comment: I've fixed that a few edits ago. Should be fine now.

Comment: Thanks, but we can enter an infinite number of zeros(((

Comment: How is that a problem? An infinite number of zeros is still a zero value.

Comment: Yes, as a programmer I understand you, but for the user this is not entirely correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255930/discussion-between-tao-and-paul).

Comment: Unfortunately, until now the user can enter a value less than five seconds (with a zero value in minutes), and can also enter a value greater than 20 minutes, for example 20 minutes and 30 seconds. It can be fixed?

Comment: I removed the first example. And the second one doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Thank you, only here the value of 13 minutes 85 seconds turns into 14 minutes 25 seconds, but should be 13 minutes 59 seconds

Comment: Not really. `85"` equals `1'25"`, not `59"`. By your logic, `7 + 5` should equal `9` in decimal.

Comment: But if you want it to work that way, you can always replace the last `val` inside `setValue` with `limitVal(0, 59, val)`, like this: `minutes ? val * 60 + (prev % 60) : ~~(prev / 60) * 60 + limitValue(0, 59, val)`. Keep in mind this will stop the minutes from changing up/down when pressing arrow keys inside the seconds input. So when pressing up from `0'59"` it won't automatically go to `1'00"`, which makes more sense for humans who haven't skipped math in school.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I noticed that currently you can enter a "dot" (.) in any of the fields. Is it possible to somehow process this?

Comment: @Paul, you can't ask a different question in a comment, because other users who might be interested in the answer have no way of finding it. You have to ask it as a different question. And yes, it's possible, but it's an anti-pattern, because if you have `a = {'b.c': 'some-value' }`, you can only access it using `a['b.c']` but not as `a.b.c`. Basically, if you have a path of a nested property, you need to know which props are actually glued with dot and which are not to read the data.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots).

Answer (score -1):

You can validate it using onChange handler of input.

```
   <input value={month} maxlength="2" onChange={(e) => {
         validationFunc(e.target.value)
         setMonth(e.target.value);
    }}/>
```

You can validate input data in validtionFunc.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Not fully tested but you could try an approach like this.

Once you have set the input fields with the appropriate `type` attribute, such as `type='number'` and ensure that the `min` and `max` attributes are set to your criteria ( max 20mins, min 5sec ) you can then use a delegated listener bound to a suitable parent (the document in this case but could/should be  more focused) that monitors the `input` event.

The event handler identifies all the `input` elements of relevance ( by name here ) and performs some basic operations on the values of each to create a total time value in seconds. If that time value is beyond your limits warn the user &/or set your own default value.

```js
document.addEventListener('input',e=>{
  if( ['minutes','seconds'].includes( e.target.name ) ){
    
    const mapcallback=(n)=>n.name=='minutes' ? n.value * 60 : n.value;
    const reducecallback=(a,b)=>a+parseInt(b);
    /*
      find the numeric input elements,
      convert minutes to seconds and
      create sum of both mins & secs values.
    */
    let total=[...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]')]
        .map( mapcallback )
        .reduce( reducecallback, 0 );
    
    /* warn the user if selected values are out of range.*/
    if( total < 5 ){
      console.log('Must be at least 5s');
    }
    if( total > 1200 ){
      console.log('Can be no more than 1200s / 20mins');
      document.querySelector('[name="seconds"]').value=0;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input name='minutes' type='number' min=0 max=20 value=0 maxlength=2 />
    <span>m</span>
  </label>
  
  <label>
    <input name='seconds' type='number' min=5 max=59 value=5 maxlength=2 />
    <span>s</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I downvoted here: binding a callback on every single input in the document to then filter running the code based on matching its name is a poor pattern, especially when used inside a [SO] answer, supposed to also be aimed at users with a similar problem. It has a huge potential to create unwanted implementation issues, IMHO.

Comment: there is only a single listener so unsure what `binding a callback on every single input in the document` means.

Comment: I do like the idea of using a single value (in seconds) and calculating if it's between 5 and 1200, though. That's how it should be done. But I'd still use `useState()`

Comment: But `useState` and `React` have introduced wholly new technology not referenced to by the OP and a level of complexity way beyond many - but I appreciate the feedback

Comment: When using `document.addEventListener('input', callback)`, `callback` will be called on every `input` event of every `<input>` in the document. You also need to cleanup on unmount, to avoid errors after the component has been unmounted, if the binding is done inside a react component. Binding on `document` when using React is not a good pattern, IMHO. That's my point.

Comment: I did mention that the delegated listener should be more focused - ie: bound to a suitable parent but given the little amount of HTML  cited in the question  it was not clear what that suitable parent would be. And I **now** see the Op **did** reference `react` so apologies.